# How does java.util.EnumSet<E> work?

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, enums

The `EnumSet<E>` class is defined as:

```
public abstract class EnumSet<E extends Enum<E>>
extends AbstractSet<E>
implements Cloneable, Serializable
```

in JCF.
Also, most of the methods that the class itself implements are static. Lastly, the class does not seem to implement the `add()`,`iterator()`,`remove()`,`size()`,`contains()` or `isEmpty()` methods and just inherits them from AbstractSet which doesn't implement them.
I have two questions:

1. How exactly `EnumSet` objects are instantiated and used?
2. Why can i use the `add()` method for `EnumSet` objects?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most of the static methods you see are *factory* methods (`of()`, `complementOf()`, `allOf()`, etc.).

These methods return an instance of EnumSet. The actual type of the EnumSet created and returned by these methods is a subclass of EnumSet (`RegularEnumSet`, `JumboEnumSet`), which are not part of the public API, but implement all the required methods. All you need to know is that they implement EnumSet.

Answer (score 9):

EnumSet is an abstract class itself, so it doesn't have to implement any abstract methods it inherits.  It passes that responsibility on to its non-abstract subclasses.

You can call the unimplemented methods because you're actually calling them on an instance of a subclass of EnumSet.  (As EnumSet is abstract, it cannot be directly instantiated itself.)

Comment: You should include that the EnumSet implements the interfaces that AbstractSet implements.  This insures that add(),iterator(),remove(),... is in the contract for EnumSet.

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.*;
enum Foo {
  A, B
}
class a {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(EnumSet.noneOf(Foo.class));
    System.out.println(EnumSet.of(Foo.A));
    System.out.println(EnumSet.of(Foo.A).getClass());
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
[]
[A]
class java.util.RegularEnumSet
```

As regards implementation, [this](http://java67.blogspot.com/2013/11/difference-between-regularenumset-and-jumboenumset-java.html) link provides a description:

> `EnumSet` is an abstract class and it provides two concrete
>   implementations, `java.util.RegularEnumSet` and `java.util.JumboEnumSet`.
>   Main difference between `RegularEnumSet` and `JumboEnumSet` is that former
>   uses a `long` variable to store elements while later uses a `long[]` to
>   store its element. Since `RegularEnumSet` uses `long` variable, which is a
>   64 bit data type, it can only hold that much of element. That's why
>   when an empty `EnumSet` is created using `EnumSet.noneOf()` method, it
>   choose `RegularEnumSet` if key universe (number of enum instances in Key
>   Enum) is less than or equal to 64 and `JumboEnumSet` if key universe is
>   more than 64.

What this means is that `EnumSet` will choose the right implementation for you.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. *How exactly EnumSet objects are instantiated and used?*

The EnumSet is an "abstract class" and is preferred than HashSet when you have a number of "keys" that it is known in advance. For example when you have a configuration keys.

The **performance** are better than **HashSet** because "*... since Enum constants are unique and has pre-defined length, as you can not define a new enum constant at runtime; it allows Java API designer to highly optimize EnumSet ..." (Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-use-enumset-in-java-with-example.html#ixzz3jNcyB8ve)*

You can instantiate with a lot of factory method, for example *EnumSet.of(...)*

> 2. *Why can i use the add() method for EnumSet objects?*

After you have created an "*EnumSet*" object you can add at run-time another element with the *"add"* method. If you have for example a list of configuration keys you can represent by EnumSet the "selected" keys and add them at runtime.

```
package sample.test;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class Foo {

  public enum SimpleConfigEnum { KEY1, KEY2, KEY3};

/**
 * Example of EnumSet with add
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Create an enumSet with two elements: KEY1,KEY2
    EnumSet<SimpleConfigEnum> eSet = EnumSet.of(SimpleConfigEnum.KEY1, SimpleConfigEnum.KEY2);
    System.out.println(eSet);

    //... add another element --> KEY3
    eSet.add(SimpleConfigEnum.KEY3);
    System.out.println(eSet);
  }

 }
```

The output is:

```
[KEY1, KEY2]
[KEY1, KEY2, KEY3]
```